# Audiokit: (V5) Sequencer cannot play notes simultaneously at the same position in a track

Tags: audiokit

I have used Audiokit's both AKAppleSequencer and AKSequencer for 2 years now. This is my first iteration getting used to the new V5 version of the library. For whatever reason, I cannot get more than a single note to play simultaneously.

Below is a very simple example of what I am trying to do:

```swift
public func setupSequencerForInterval(note1: MIDINoteNumber, note2: MIDINoteNumber) {

        sequencer.clear()
        sequencer = Sequencer(targetNode: sampler)
        sequencer.tempo = 120
        sequencer.loopEnabled = false
        sequencer.length = 12.0

        sequencer.add(noteNumber: note1, velocity: 127, channel: 1, position: 0.0, duration: 4.0, trackIndex: 0)
        sequencer.add(noteNumber: note2, velocity: 127, channel: 1, position: 4.0, duration: 4.0, trackIndex: 0)
        sequencer.add(noteNumber: note1, velocity: 127, channel: 1, position: 8.0, duration: 4.0, trackIndex: 0)
        sequencer.add(noteNumber: note2, velocity: 127, channel: 1, position: 8.0, duration: 4.0, trackIndex: 0)

    }
```

[Here is what it sounds like](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gkt3ysuen4rox1j/no_polyphony.MP4?dl=0)

A sequence of 3 whole notes: 1st whole note on `note1`, 2nd whole note on `note2`, 3rd whole note both `note1` and `note2` playing together.

I have tested my sampler to make sure it was not monophonic, and it can play notes polyphonically.

Stranger yet, if I change the last line of (adding the note 2 whole note at the same position as note 1 at position 8.0) to a position of *anything greater* than 8.0, the *effect* of polyphony occurs. [You can hear that here, a value of 8.01 was used for `position` on the last `sequencer.add` call](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9gnl4ab2c8n892g/polyphony.MP4?dl=0)

Is this intended behavior? Is `Sequencer` not supposed to play multiple notes at the same position? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the AudioKit team, this is *not* intended behavior and is being looked into: https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues/2409